# reload data in inputs after PRE_SUBMIT add an error to a filed in symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony, events

i create a form in App\Forms. i need custom validation so add a PRE_SUBMIT listener to my form. But when i click in submit and pre_submit add an error, reloaded form build with new form and my data lost.

what can i do to keep my data in inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Form events are not a good place for form validation. For your custom validation, it's better to write a custom validation constraint class and use that in your form definition.

Follow this for writing custom validation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

and follow this to use your created custom validation constraint in your form class:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes